# Automatically answer to input prompt of batch script run by Python

Tags: python, batch-file

This is rather a unusual use case where I had to make a legacy system to work.

I have Windows batch script like following named 'batch_test.bat' (example only):

```
@echo OFF
set /P choice=Enter your choice: 

if /I "%choice%" == "N" (
    echo "Don't proceed"
)

if /I "%choice%" == "Y" (
    echo "Proceed"
)
if /I "%choice%" == "C" (
    echo "Cancel"

)
EXIT /B 0
```

I have following python code (sample):

```
import os

os.system('batch_test.bat')
```

Question is how do I feed the choice batch script is expecting from Python? I did some look up but could not find the appropriate answer.

thanks.

Comment: If you read the docs for [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities… using that module is preferable to using this function…" If you want to control the stdin of a program, or capture its stdout, or run it safely without using the shell, or anything else, use `subprocess`, not `os.system`.

Comment: And notice that the docs linked to from that paragraph, [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements), include examples that feed input into other programs, exactly what you haven't been able to find.

Comment: Note that `echo "some text"` includes the quotes in the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` to provide input to a process:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen('batch_test.bat', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output, _ = p.communicate(b'Y\n')
```

Comment: This worked! Deep within I found some doc that explains it in subtle way: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen